# Read/Write Excel files with Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

So in the project I'm working on, many calculations are made in an excel file. This excel file expects an input in certain cells with which he shows certain results ( set in other cells). I was going to translate those calculations in code. But Ithe number of factors to translate would be to time-consuming.

Is there a way to write on certain cells and reading from other cells with javascript?

I've come across many "translators" like

- `exceljs`(but dependent cells could not be read properly),
- `xlsx-populate` (didn't understand why it didn't work),
- `js-xlsx`(didn't install properly).
- I also considered `ActiveXObject`, but since those are only working on IE, it is not worth.

If anyone has a solution, the help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In the browser?, or on a server (Node.js)?

Comment: @Lawnio, it would be easier to help if we can see what you tried

Comment: Preferably on a server, @david25272

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using the [spreadSheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs#prerequisites) of Google. With `NodeJs`, you can use the fonction below

```js
function excelFileProcessing(auth) {
    var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
    //Read the values of the range B1:E1 in the sheet1
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth: auth,
        spreadsheetId: 'the id of your spread sheet',
        range: 'sheet1!B1:E1',
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            res.send(500);
        }
        var rows = response.values;
        if (rows.length === 0) {
            console.log('No data found.');
        } else {
            // Write the values in the range B2:E2 of your spread sheet
            var body = {
                values: rows
            };
            sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
                auth: auth,
                spreadsheetId: 'the id of your spread sheet',
                range: 'sheet1!B2:E2',
                valueInputOption: 'RAW',
                resource: body
            }, function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    // Handle error
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(500)
                } else {
                    console.log('%d cells updated.', result.updatedCells);
                    res.send(rows)
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

});
```